# layout_gravity работает неверно (android)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Добрый день! Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться с layout_gravity. 
Сделал свой Compound View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/imt_btn_root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_bg_service_rep"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/img_btn_ll_tvs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/img_btn_tv_head"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/img_btn_tv_hint"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/img_btn_ll_imgs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_btn_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

И сам класс:

```
public class ImageTextButton extends LinearLayout {

private int layoutType;
private String textHead, textHint;
private Drawable drawable;

private TextView tvHead, tvHint;
private ImageView iv;

public ImageTextButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray typedArray = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ImageTextButton);
    layoutType = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.ImageTextButton_imageGravity, 0);
    textHead = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.ImageTextButton_textHead);
    textHint = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.ImageTextButton_textHint);
    drawable = typedArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.ImageTextButton_android_drawable);
    typedArray.recycle();
    initializeViews(context);

}

private void initializeViews(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_text_button_mockup_r, this);
}

private void setupValues () {
    CharSequence chHead = textHead;
    CharSequence chHint = textHint;

    tvHead.setText(chHead);
    tvHint.setText(chHint);
    iv.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();

    tvHead = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_tv_head);
    tvHint = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_tv_hint);
    iv = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_image);

    setupValues();
}
```

}

Выглядит это так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при добавлении этого view в activity_main, ImageView, которому присвоены параметры layout_gravity `bottom|right` рисуется не в правом нижнем углу, а выше. При чем margin равен 0. В чем может быть проблема? Я где-то допустил ошибку? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо за помощь!

Также, XML activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <view
        android:id="@+id/imgTbService"
        class="com.paveloleynik.autoservice.customviews.ImageTextButton"
        id="@+id/view2"
        layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawable="@drawable/service_btn"
        app:imageGravity="right"
        app:textHead="@string/login_service_1"
        app:textHint="@string/login_service_2" />

    <view
        android:id="@+id/imgTbClient"
        class="com.paveloleynik.autoservice.customviews.ImageTextButton"
        id="@+id/view"
        layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawable="@drawable/client_btn"
        app:imageGravity="left"
        app:textHead="@string/login_client"
        app:textHint="@string/login_client_2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Попробуйте у `ImageView` поставить добавить параметр `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сработало. Также, изменил `bottom|right` на `bottom|end`

Comment: @PashaOleynik выкиньте ещё "лишние" обертки вокруг view: FrameLayout, LinearLayout (тот, в котором только ImageView)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При установке у `ImageView` некоторых `scaleType` (`centerInside`, в данном случае), размеры `ImageView` и самого изображения могут не совпадать. Отсюда и образуются эти отступы.

Чтобы этого избежать, нужно использовать параметр:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Он подгоняет размеры самого изображения под размер `ImageView`.